# Exam question. Limits of sequences

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Question given is this:

Given an increasing sequence of non-negative real numbers $(a_n)_{n=1}^∞$, let
$s_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k.$
Prove that if $s_n \to x$ as $n \to ∞$ for some $x\in \mathbb{R}$ then also $a_n \to x$ as $n \to ∞$.

Is this a valid proof in an undergraduate Y1 exam, even with a few details missing? I am having difficulty seeing a shorter way when one most probably exists.

Firstly I proved $(a_n)_n$ is convergent:

$(a_n)_n$ must be bounded above by contradiction. Assume, for the sake of contradiction that it is not bounded above. Then as $n \to ∞$, $a_n \to ∞$. But then for some large enough M, for all $n>M$, $a_n>K$ where $K$ is arbitrary. But then $s_n>1/n\sum_{M+1}^nK=(n-M)K/n$ and so $s_n$ has no finite limit. Hence by contradiction it is bounded above.

By the monotone convergence theorem an increasing sequence bounded above is also convergent hence $(a_n)_n$ converges.

Consider: $s_n-x=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(a_k-x).$

Now let the limit of $(a_n)_n$ be $l$. Suppose, for the sake contradiction $l>x$. Let $a>0$. Then by the definition of convergence for large enough M for all $n>M$, $a_n>x+a$. Hence, as $n \to ∞$, $s_n-x>(1/n)a\sum_{M+1}^∞(1)=a$ and so $0>a$. But this is not zero, hence contradiction. By symmetry the same is true for $l<x$. 
Hence, $l=x$.

There are some holes here but I was wondering if they are significant in your view in an exam situation. Also, what is the smaller expected proof I should be giving.

Comment: $s_n > \frac{1}{n} \sum_{M+1}^\infty K =K$ is wrong. $s_n$ is an average of a finite sum, so $\infty$ should not show up. Also, the RHS is not $K$.

Comment: Thanks, I have changed it now.

Comment: I am looking for comments about whether I am missing any important reasoning.

Comment: Once you have arrived the step: $s_n > (n-M)K/n$, it is unclear why $(s_n)$ cannot have finite limit. You need to clarify the dependancy between $K$, $n$, $M$.

Answer (score 1):

Prove by contradiction. Suppose the contrary that $(a_{n})$ is unbounded,
then $a_{n}\rightarrow\infty$ because it is increasing. Let $K>0$
be arbitrary, then there exists $N$ such that $a_{n}\geq K$ whenever
$n\geq N$. For any $n\geq N$, we have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
s_{n} & = & \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}\\
 & \geq & \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=N}^{n}a_{k}\\
 & \geq & \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=N}^{n}K\\
 & = & K\cdot\frac{n-N+1}{n}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Letting $n\rightarrow\infty$, by Sandwich rule, we have $x=\lim_{n}s_{n}\geq K,$
which is a contradiction because $K>0$ is arbitrary. (For example,
choose $K=x+1$, then we have $x\geq x+1$, which is absurd)